# Avoid Blood lyse color remain in DNA extraction

Tags: protocol, dna-isolation, biochemistry, bioinorganic-chemistry

I tryed several times to extract DNA from freezed blood sample whit Qiagene kit but it gave very small amount of product due to good purity then I try extract manually by using CTAB PVP method and finaly gain a much more DNA but the lysate color in sample remain in DNA pellet an do not disolve in any solvent to seperation I tried to add small amount of accorbic acid but just the color get reduce to red from gray:'( . If every one have a idea which can help me please gave in a small answer.

Comment: Sounds like your DNA isn't pure.

Comment: The kit likely has a way of dealing with the RBCs, where as your CTAB PVP may not. Did you centrifuge the sample? If human, RBCs are not going to have genomic DNA, so you can extract the WBC layer and plasma and try purifying that.